# How to set example values in @ApiModelProperty in such a way that different values are returned for HTTP status codes?

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, springfox

I have a class called `ErrorDetails` which is a template for all error responses.

```
public class ErrorDetails {
  private Date timestamp;
  private String message;
  private String details;
  private int code;

  public ErrorDetails(Date timestamp, String message, String details, int code) {
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
    this.message = message;
    this.details = details;
    this.code = code;
  }
}
```

Now, in order to display example values, we use swagger annotations: `@ApiModel` & `@ApiModelProperty` . But I want to display different samples for respective error responses.
For example, `code 400`, should have sample message: `Page not found` and for `code 500` will ahve different sample message. How do I achieve that? I can only specify one example value for a specific case. Is there a way to programmatically handle sample values?  I have explored below ways:

1. **Having a generic response set at global docket config**:
   Problem here is I might have different error response for code 404 alone. For example : "Employee not found", "Store not found" etc. This is impossible to achieve if I have global configuration.
2. **Using `@Example` with `@ApiResponse`**:
   Problem here is this is not working &  springfox dev team suggest to use `@ApiModelProperty` instead of this approach.

`@ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Internal server error", response = ErrorDetails.class, examples = @Example(value = @ExampleProperty(value = "{\"timestamp\": \"1598947603319\", \"message\":\"Operation failed\", \"details\":\"Operation failed due to Runtime exception\", \"code\": \"500\"}", mediaType = "application/json")))`

The above code is not working and I get the below output:
[image]

Can someone suggest me how to fix the above issue ? or how to set values dynamically in `@ApiModelProperty` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, I had to create different classes representing each one of these errors and link them from `@ApiResponse`. There's no way that I can have one single model class that can throw varying sample responses for all different HTTP status.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to only display what message is attached to which status code, then here's example

```
    @PostMapping(value = "/api/posts")
    @ApiOperation(value = "Create post.")
    @ApiResponses({
        @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Post created successfully", response = PostResponse.class),
        @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "Blog does not exist", response = ApiError.class),
        @ApiResponse(code = 409, message = "Post already exists", response = ApiError.class),
        @ApiResponse(code = 422, message = "Block content full", response = ApiError.class)
})
PostResponse createPost(...){
  ...
}
```